# php echo string cannot be checked in javascript by innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, echo, innerhtml

I'm quite new to php and javascript and I come up with some problems.
In my php file(i.e. a.php), I type code like this:

```
<?php
...(checking sth in database)...
if($found == 0)
echo "Valid";
else echo "Not Valid";
?>
```

Then, in my another php file, I pass form data to a.php for checking whether there are duplicate of records in the database, if no, it will print "Valid" in the label through AJAX:

```
function ajax(str){
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("e").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    var data = 'Email='+ str;
    xhttp.open("POST", "a.php" , true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(data);
}
```

This is my label:

```
<label style="color: red;" id="e"></label>
```

I want to check whether the label value is "Valid" or not, then i wrote code like this:

```
var email = document.getElementById("e").innerHTML;
if (email == "Valid")
    test.innerHTML = "it works!"; //test is another paragragh tag with id="test"
```

However I can't print "it works!", I've tried to echo another value (i.e. echo "1";), and when I type

```
if (email == 1)
```

it can print out "it works!".
Do anyone know why is this happening and what should I do if I want to print "Valid"?

Comment: can you use `console.log(document.getElementById("e").innerHTML);` to check the value of `email` here?

Comment: What can you see, when you check ajax request using browsers debug tools Network tab?

Comment: otherwise you can try with `console.log(document.getElementById("e").innerText);`

Comment: both  console.log(document.getElementById("e").innerHTML);   and    console.log(document.getElementById("e").innerText); won't work

Comment: @RauliRajande Before clicking it just show the original php file, after clicking calling ajax function it add another php file(i.e. a.php) on the list

Comment: Main logic is correct, your code should work ok. I think you have a mistake in some small moment. F.e. uppercase vs lowercase, or empty space after a string etc...   Write alert(email);  before the var email = document.getElementById("e").innerHTML; line and tell me what you get as alert message: "Valid" or "Not valid"?

Comment: @Elvin85 not sure if I am understanding it correctly because email is not declared before var email = document.getElementById("e").innerHTML; line, if i did that email with alert before that line, then it will print undefined, but if i put that after that line, it prints Valid

Comment: yes, sorry, i meant after that line, not before. So you say that 'if (email == "Valid")' doesn't work, but right after that alert(email) prints 'Valid'? Sorry, but it is impossible :) Check if there is some empty space before of after "Valid" string. You can do it by alerting this after that row:  alert(email.length);   Tell me do you get 5 or 6 or what?

Comment: @Elvin85 Omg...it is getting 8...how should I find the missing characters?

Comment: Try removing ?> from a.php. May be you have some spaces after closing that tag.

Comment: Check also my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If alerting email variable dislays "Valid" but if (email=='Valid') returns false, it means you have some additional characters in returned AJAX data.

So, try removing them with

- Closing ?> tag in a.php (or removing spaces after ?> tag)
- Making sure that database checking section doesn't print anything.
- And you can also use alternative way to check that condition.

For example, you can do it so:

```
//var email = document.getElementById("e").innerHTML;
//if (email == "Valid")
var email = document.getElementById("e").innerHTML;
if (email.indexOf("Not")==-1)
   test.innerHTML = "it works!";
```

Comment: I've tried removing that tag but seemed not working, I am now using if(email.length == 8) test.innerHTML="it works!". Although it might be a little bit stupid, it works. Thanks for reminding that length can use to check whether additional characters. Thank you!